# How to locate the element using XPath Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I need to get the number "3" from this HTML with python selenium

```
<div class="number">3</div>
```

This is the XPATH:

```
//*[@id="roulette-recent"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div
```

I tried something like

```
number = navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rouletterecent"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div').get_attribute('class')
```

Answer (score 1):

If this xpath

```
//*[@id="rouletterecent"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div
```

represent the node:

```
<div class="number">3</div>
```

and you want to extract the text from it, you should use either:

```
number = navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rouletterecent"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div').get_attribute('innerText')
print(number)
```

or

```
number = navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rouletterecent"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div').text
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```py
number = navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rouletterecent"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div').text
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the text ***3*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(navegador.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#roulette-recent div.number").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="roulette-recent"]//div[@class='number' and text()]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#roulette-recent div.number"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="roulette-recent"]//div[@class='number' and text()]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)